# Javascript - Unable to convert string to number

Tags: javascript, typescript, parsing, text, browser

Im creating a string parser app, This is my app flow

1. select all text in a website from a browser
2. paste it on my site, and it will convert it into something

The problem is when i tried to convert a string number using either `Number(myString)` or `parseInt(myString)` i got `NaN`.
But when i use a dummy variable like `let i = "19"` , it will correctly convert it to number.

What i have tried is converting my string to urlEncoded format, and the result is:
for string ‭`21‬` , the encoded result is `%E2%80%AD21%E2%80%AC`

So i am concluding that the string that i got from copy pasting in a web browser is unparseable due to some kind of formatting.

How do i fix this behaviour?

Comment: The easiest way to help but to be able to see what you're actually getting from the browser before you parse it. 

Chances are you're catching some other data which isn't a number.

Comment: sample string that i got from browser `‭‭(‭19‬|‭−‭14‬‬)‬‬` is encoded to: `%E2%80%AD%28%E2%80%AD19%E2%80%AC%7C%E2%80%AD%E2%88%92%E2%80%AD14%E2%80%AC%E2%80%AC%29%E2%80%AC`

you can urldecode my string and play with the value

Comment: `+decodeURIComponent('%E2%80%AD21%E2%80%AC').replace(/^.(.*).$/, '$1')` seems to work

Comment: What's it worth of, if we'd implement our own parser, it's _your parser_ which doesn't work here, and if we can't see the code, we can't fix your parser either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `replace(/[^\x20-\x7E]/g, '')` to replace non-printable ASCII chars like so:

```js
const sillyString = decodeURIComponent("%E2%80%AD21%E2%80%AC");
console.log(sillyString);
console.log(parseInt(sillyString));
console.log(parseInt(sillyString.replace(/[^\x20-\x7E]/g, '')));
```

Maybe that will help?